# Dot in calculator android studio

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to build a simple calculator in android studio. Everything is fine but i have a problem, when i run the calculator and i press the dot button, it shows in the textview "." instead "0." 
Also, i need to check the existence of two decimal points in a single numeric value.

here is an image:

[image]

it shows "."

and i want:

[image]

how can i change this??, here is my code:

```
    private int cont=0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
    text="";
}


    public void numero1(View view){ /*when i press a number, this method executes*/
    Button button = (Button) view;
    text += button.getText().toString();
    display.setText(text);
}

    public void dot(View view){ /*This is not finished*/
    display.setText{"0."}
    }
```

I was thinking in creating another method for the dot button, but the content of the text value disappears when i press another button, how to fix this?

Comment: Use formatters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public void numero1(View view){ /*when i press a number, this method executes*/
Button button = (Button) view;
text += button.getText().toString();
if(text.substring(0,1).equals("."))
text="0"+text;    
display.setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
public void dot(View view){ /*This is not finished*/
               String str=display.getText().toString().trim();
                  if(str.length()>0){
                      display.seText(str+".")
                  }else{
                      display.setText("0.")
                  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a string builder and append all the text entered to already existing string. Before display, just use the `toString()` method on the string builder.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that represents your character sequence to be displayed and process the incoming characters.

For example:

```java
class Display {
    boolean hasPoint = false;
    StringBuilder mSequence;

    public Display() {
        mSequence = new StringBuilder();
        mSequence.append('0');
    }

    public void add(char pChar) {
        // avoiding multiple floating points
        if(pChar == '.'){
            if(hasPoint){
                return;
            }else {
                hasPoint = true;
            }
        }
        // avoiding multiple starting zeros
        if(!hasPoint && mSequence.charAt(0) == '0' && pChar == '0'){
            return;
        }
        // adding character to the sequence 
        mSequence.append(pChar);
    }

    // Return the sequence as a string
    // Integer numbers get trailing dot
    public String toShow(){
        if(!hasPoint)
            return mSequence.toString() + ".";
        else
            return mSequence.toString();
    }
}
```

Set such a click listener to your numeric and "point/dot" buttons:

```java
class ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // getting char by name of a button
        char aChar = ((Button) view).getText().charAt(0);
        // trying to add the char
        mDisplay.add(aChar);
        // displaying the result in the TextView
        tvDisplay.setText(mDisplay.toShow());
    }
}
```

Initialize the display in onCreate() of your activity:

```java
    mDisplay = new Display();
    tvDisplay.setText(mDisplay.toShow());
```